# Check if named form input is disabled using formController

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to check if a named form input on a formController scope is disabled.

Inspecting the available methods and properties I can't seem to find anything.

`$scope.formName.input_name` has various properties for $valid, $submitted, $setDirty() etc. but nothing that appears to indicate if the input is currently disabled. Would be great if it has something like `$scope.formName.input_name.$isDisabled` etc.

Comment: How are you disabling the input by ng-disabled ?

Comment: @neda yup , evaluating expression on ng-disabled

Comment: Then with the same expression you can get that its disabled if its true

Comment: My ng-disabled is set to true or false if another input in the same form is enabled or disabled, in hierarchal chain fashion. Most efficient way to do this is to simply check on the formController as I am doing this check and setting the property which is checked by ng-disabled in another function, which runs on ng-show.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>    
   <input type="text" ng-model="disableCheck" ng-disabled="valueForDisabling">
</form>
```

now , using this $scope.valueForDisabling , we can check whether form input is disabled or not.

```
 if($scope.valueForDisabling)
    alert("input type is disabled");
 else
    alert("input type is not disabled");
```